# Use font awesome icon in nuxt watcher

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, font-awesome

In my nuxt component, I know I can use the following to display an icon from Font Awesome:-

`<fa icon="circle" />`

But what do I need to do to use the same icon when I'm building HTML content in a watcher, like this:-

```
watch: {
    events(newEvents, _) {
        let infoWindowContent = ''

        newEvents.forEach((event) => {
            infoWindowContent = infoWindowContent.concat(
            `<div><fa icon="circle" /> <-- this doesn't work! </div>`
            )
        }

        const infowindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: infoWindowContent,
        })

        window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
          infowindow.open(this.map, marker)
        })
    }
}
```

?

Comment: You may have XY problem, consider updating the question with details on your case. It's unknown why it's important to keep infoWindowContent as a string. Generally you should either do that with a combo of v-for and v-if in a template, or an array in render function

Comment: Ah, fair point - it needs to be a string (I think!) because I'm using it to provide the content for a google maps InfoWindow - I'll update the code to show that. Is there another way to do this maybe?

Comment: You'd need to use Vue as template engine for that which is a workaround that allows no dynamic behaviour. There should be a way to provide dom element instead of a string to make it vue-friendly. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#customize